# Arranging data by unique value and another criteria such as date using a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet that I'm putting raw daily ticket data into. I want to summarize this data on another sheet.

```
Date     Customer    Ticket No.    Widget    Doodad    Thingy
8/1/14   ABC         1234            2         1         0
8/1/14   123         1235            0         4         6
8/1/14   XYZ         1236            4         2         1
8/1/14   ABC         1237            0         1         0
8/2/14   XYZ         1238            1         0         0
```

What I would like is a sheet that I can type the date in at the top and it summarize the data by Customer:

```
Date:  8/1/14
Customer    Widget    Doodad    Thingy
ABC           2         2         0
123           0         4         6
XYZ           4         2         1
```

I can summarize my product data with a sumifs statement.
I can get unique customer data from multiple from the method described here: [unique distinct value](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/04/14/create-a-unique-alphabetically-sorted-list-extracted-from-a-column/)

My problem is how to get it only for the singular date.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a pivot table.

Put the date into the page filter, customer into the row area, Widget, doodat and thingy into the values area, making sure to sum, not count the values.

In the page filter, select the desired date.

[image]

Comment: This does exactly what I want. Thank you!